# Sort CSS declarations alphanumerically

Tags: sorting

As [per the Google style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.html#Declaration_Order) (but this is a generally recognized as good practice) the CSS declarations should be sorted within rules blocks.

So given the following code:

```
.ruleOne {
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: blue;
}

 .ruleTwo {
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

What would be a good way (keyboard macro, defun, etc.) to end up with this?

```
.ruleOne {
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40px;
}

 .ruleTwo {
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
}
```